# Images are not displayed on phone

Tags: html, css, web

I have a question. I try open my website on pc and the main photo( on css file) is visible. When I try open website on my phone(Android) the same picture is gone.
Can somebody help me?

The main background photo of the music mixer doesn't work correctly on phones

```css
#home {
  background: url('../images/home.jpg')no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  min-height: 600px;
  padding-top: 220px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the website so we can see it? Along with the section of code that you're using trouble with? There are lots of reasons why this my be happening so it'll be much easier to answer if we know what we're dealing with

Comment: Please [edit] the post and include a [mcve] - Show us the relevant part of the code you're having problems with. You can click on the `<>` button and create a working snippet. You can also paste the code, select it, and click Ctrl+K for auto indentation

Comment: Checking that page on my phone I can see the image fine. Make sure you aren't viewing an old cached version on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Your background image is 3.7Mb -- this is huge. Your mobile phone will have trouble downloading this image on mobile broadband due to your network providers probably throttling.

---

Your page works fine on my mobile device, you will need to tell us what make of phone OS you have and the browser make/type.

You will also need to clear your phone browser history and download again, just to be sure.

Also, let us know if you're using mobile network or wifi to connect.

Comment: OK man. I am using wifi to connect. I have Samsung Galaxy A5 on Android and i am using chrome on phone

Comment: @Michael are you sure the image doesn't display *at all* or is it simply very slow to appear on the phone?

Comment: yes. I converted a phono to less size, still refreshing all the time and nothing :(

Comment: did you clear your phone cache and browser history for that website?

Comment: Also check that your mobile browser doesn't ignore files too big (such as 3.7Mb)

Comment: Yes I am sure guys

Comment: OK SOLVED. On firefox it works correcly. Thank you guys ;)

Comment: @Michael I'm glad it's fixed. If my answer helped you reach your solution please click the tick underneath the vote arrows, thanks `:-)`